# mvc3 SelectList SelectedValue is displayed but not returned in Edit view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, selectlist, selectedvalue, actionresult

I have an Edit view with the following DropDown list:

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Size, 
          new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "Size", "Size"),
          Model.Size,  
          new { id = "WoodSize" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Size)
```

The pertinent portion of the controller is:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Part part)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                unitOfWork.PartRepository.Update(part);
                unitOfWork.Save();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        catch (DataException)
        {
            //Log the error (add a variable name after DataException)
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
        }
        return View(part);
```

The SelectedValue is displayed on Get, but unless changed, it is not returned to the controller on Post, and the update fails. If the value is selected manually, the selection is returned and the update succeeds. It seems that SelectValue does not actually select anything but only displays default text.

I have to be missing something, but I'm at a loss as to what.

Answer (score 0):

You third parameter is only a label so that you can have the drop down say "Select Size" for example, it does not contain a value. In your instance your using the Model.Size value as the label

If your Model value matches a value in the list of options availalbe it will then mark it as selected, and thus send the value to your controller when you submit.